# GIT osx command line can push to existing repo, can't create new

Tags: git, macos, github, ssh, push

Yesterday I created a new Github repo using the following git commands in the osx command line:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

Now when I make a change to this repo and I add, commit and push the changes everything works perfectly fine.

Now I'd try the same with a new repo, but I keep getting the following errors:

> No configured push destination.

So I've tried adding the remote repo using the following command:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:ronnyrr/OverlayModel.git
```

Which seems to work (no error), but the repo **isn't** created on my Github account. 
So after that I push using:

```
git push origin master
```

Still doesn't work, the following error shows up:

> ERROR: Repository not found. 
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

But the strange thing is that when I run the `git remote add` command again it prints:

> fatal: remote origin already exists.

Although the repository isn't created in my Github account..
When I'm using the `curl` command to create a repository, the repo **does** shows up in my Github account:

```
curl -u 'ronnyrr' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"OverlayModel"}'
```

Unfortunately I'm still not able to push changes using commands like:

```
git push OverlayModel master:master
git push --set-upstream OverlayModel master:master
```

Gives the following error:

> fatal: 'OverlayModel' does not appear to be a git repository fatal:
>   Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I'd change to SSH key using in Github, no success. After changing the key I can still push changes to existing repo's. Not with `push` nor `push origin master`. To be sure, I do only have a master branch.

Anyone knows whats up? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could it possibly be the capitalization of your username in the git@github...? I notice your other repos have a capitalized `Ronnyrr`.

Comment: I've added the code I used for creating a repo using the curl command. Here it does work with lowercase and it does show up in my Github account.

Comment: You can't push to a repository on github that doesn't exist.  I don't see the step here where you created the github repository?  Also, note that `git remote add` is just setting a name:value pair in your configuration; it doesn't perform any sort of check on the remote repository.  "fatal: remote origin already exists" simply means "you've already configured that".

Comment: @larsks thanks for your useful reply. Can you point out which step I'm missing to remotely create a repo?

Comment: You would need to use the web interface, or use the github api to create the repository (or use something like [hub](https://github.com/github/hub) that provides a cli interface to the api).